# How to set default Text in Android Spinner

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner, baseadapter, pojo

I am displaying values in spinner. I want to display default text like "Select Table".  Here's my code

```
    JSONArray tablearray = tablenamejson.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < tablearray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = tablearray.getJSONObject(i);
    String table_id = jsonObject.getString(TAG_TABLE_ID);
    String table_name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_TABLE_NAME);
    ArrayList<TableData> tableDatas = new ArrayList<TableData>();
    TableData tables = new TableData();
    tables.setTblId(table_id);
    tables.setTblName(table_name);
    tableDatas.add(tables);
    }

    adapter = new TableAdapter(tableDatas, getActivity());
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I recommend adding some more specific information in your title.  Formatting your code to be more readable, and asking a specific question (with information about what isn't working, etc.)

Comment: This is the exact question and i am received answer and it's working fine. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you should declare

```
ArrayList<TableData> tableDatas = new ArrayList<TableData>();
```

outside `forloop` as you are adding all the entries in that `list`

add your default value first inside `list` then write `forloop` for adding all the values in `json array` and then use `spinner.setSelection(0);` method to show defult value in spinner as you have added it in 1st position in an `array`

following is code

```
ArrayList<TableData> tableDatas = new ArrayList<TableData>();

//for default value
TableData tables = new TableData();
tables.setTblId(0);
tables.setTblName("Select");
tableDatas.add(tables);

JSONArray tablearray = tablenamejson.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < tablearray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObject = tablearray.getJSONObject(i);
  String table_id = jsonObject.getString(TAG_TABLE_ID);
  String table_name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_TABLE_NAME);
  TableData tables = new TableData();
  tables.setTblId(table_id);
  tables.setTblName(table_name);
  tableDatas.add(tables);
}

adapter = new TableAdapter(tableDatas, getActivity());
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spinner .setSelection() to achieve this .

```
String myString = "Select Table"; //default value for spinner 

ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) mySpinner.getAdapter(); 

int spinpos= myAdap.getPosition(myString);

//set the default according to value
spinner.setSelection(spinpos);
```